# if stament in shell script

Tags: bash, scripts

How write in `if [ -z $str1 && -z $str2 ]`, `"&&"` doesn't work, if write `[ -z $str1 ]` this is work. I want to once two string

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter first string"
read str1

echo "Enter second string"
read str2

if [ -z $str1 && -z $str2 ];    
then    
    echo "firs and second string length is zero"
else    
    echo "firs and second string length is not zero"    
fi
```

Comment: @JacobVlijm ok, can you help me?

Comment: try -a instead of &&. see man test

Comment: FYI: Next time, pure script coding question should be on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-a` in place of `&&`. From `man test`

```
   EXPRESSION1 -a EXPRESSION2
          both EXPRESSION1 and EXPRESSION2 are true
```

The `&&` form of logical AND operator is valid within bash's extended test construct `[[ ... ]]`, but not inside tests of the form `[ ... ]`.

Answer (score 4):

I am not the bash specialist on AU, but I have the feeling you mean:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter first string"
read str1

echo "Enter second string"
read str2

if [ -z "$str1" ] && [ -z "$str2" ]; then    
    echo "first and second string length is zero"
else    
    echo "first and second string length is not zero"    
fi
```

So that the output is "first and second string length is zero" only if both lengths are zero, right?